# Erro ao testar o sandbox da cielo

Tags: java, web-service, rest

**Ao acessar as urls** https://apiquerysandbox.cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br/1/sales/{PaymentId}
ao substituir PaymentId por um valor: 1 (valor aleatorio)

**Recebo esta mensagem:** 
"Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

O método da API é GET. Apenas troque no Postman para GET ao invés de POST

[image: Requisição]